# NSMutable Array - objectAtIndex: index beyond bounds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to look through a NSMutableDictionary loaded with an NSMutableArray and I'm messing it up, and I don't know how.  I'm trying to load a larger plist of game questions, then delete them if they aren't the right level.  I don't get an error until I try and delete.  Can anyone see the flaw in this code?  I'd super appreciate it!

Thanks,

~G

```
{
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *GameLevel = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: [settings objectForKey:kLevelKey]];

NSBundle *Bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *PListPath = [Bundle pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *Dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PListPath]; 

self.QuestionDetailsByLevel = Dictionary;
[Dictionary release];

NSMutableArray *Components = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[QuestionDetailsByLevel allKeys]];
self.QuestionsByLevel = Components;

int QuestionCount = [self.QuestionsByLevel count] - 1;

for (int j = 0; j < QuestionCount - 1; j++)
{

    NSString *SelectedQuestion = [self.QuestionsByLevel objectAtIndex:j];
    NSMutableArray *Array = [QuestionDetailsByLevel objectForKey:SelectedQuestion];
    self.QDetailsByLevel = Array;

    NSString *level = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[self.QDetailsByLevel objectAtIndex:Level]];

    if (level != GameLevel)
        [QuestionsByLevel removeObjectAtIndex:j];   
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you put everything in one plist? Just have one for each level, and then just load the one you need.

Answer (score 10):

Barring the other issues mentioned by everyone else, let's focus on why you're getting an out-of-bounds error.

Here's the code that's relevant.

```
for (int j = 0; j < QuestionCount - 1; j++)
{

    NSString *SelectedQuestion = [self.QuestionsByLevel objectAtIndex:j];
    // ... snip ...
    if (level != GameLevel) //Always happening in your current code
        [QuestionsByLevel removeObjectAtIndex:j];       
}
```

Let's see what happens after a few iterations of this code.

First iteration:

```
j == 0
self.QuestionsByLevel == [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]

SelectedQuestion = QuestionsByLevel[0] // Q1

// The following happens because you call removeObjectAtIndex:0
QuestionsByLevel = [Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
```

Second Iteration:

```
j == 1
self.QuestionsByLevel == [Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
SelectedQuestion = QuestionsByLevel[1] // Q3

// The following happens because you call removeObjectAtIndex:1
QuestionsByLevel = [Q2, Q4, Q5]
```

Third Iteration:

```
j == 2
self.QuestionsByLevel == [Q2, Q4, Q5]
SelectedQuestion = QuestionsByLevel[2] // Q5

// The following happens because you call removeObjectAtIndex:2
QuestionsByLevel = [Q2, Q4]
```

Fourth Iteration:

```
j == 3
self.QuestionsByLevel == [Q2, Q4]
SelectedQuestion = QuestionsByLevel[3] // CRASH!!!!
```

Can you see the problem?  Your for loop assumes you'll access the objects by their index, but then after each iteration, you're deleting something out of the array, which shifts all the indexes after that point. You shouldn't be calling `removeObjectAtIndex:`, because you're trying to walk through the array at the same time.

If you're just trying to skip a specific object, you could just call "continue" when you reach that object.  If you're actually wanting to remove it out of the array, just call `[QuestionsByLevel removeObject:GameLevel]`.  Or whatever makes sense for your situation.  But do that *before* you iterate through the array.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer.  This is a critique of your code.

1. Holy memory leaks, Batman!  You alloc/init: `GameLevel`, `Components`, and `level`, but never release any of them.
2. `GameLevel` doesn't need to be alloc/init'd at all.  You can just pull the value out of `[settings objectForKey:kLevelKey];`, assign it into your `GameLevel` string, and use that.  Then you don't even have to release it.
3. Your loop is... odd.  You're iterating through the loop, but each time you iterate, you set the `self.QDetailsByLevel` property to a new value.  Are you sure that's what you want?
4. This: `if (level != GameLevel)` does not do what you think it does.  That's comparing pointers (ie, the ADDRESSES of two objects in memory).  In your current state, both `level` and `GameLevel` have been alloc/init'd, which means they will *never* be the same object.  You're probably wanting `if ([level isEqualToString:GameLevel] == NO)` instead.
5. You subtract one from `[self.QuestionsByLevel count]` to get your `QuestionCount` int, which would appear to be an upper bound on a for() loop.  Yet the conditional on the for loop (which @Michael showed to be your problem) subtracts *another* 1 from `QuestionCount`, which means that your for() loop will never reach the last element in the array.  Are you sure that's what you want?
6. Memorize this: http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php (or [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146))

Comment: Also, don't let the user provide format strings. `initWithFormat:[settings objectForKey…]` is always wrong. The user *will* write a format string that is valid, but expects arguments you're not giving it. Then your app will crash. Always pass either a constant string (`@"…"`) or a localized version of one (`NSLocalizedString(@"…", /*comment*/ @"Explanation of the string")`.

Comment: I also question the presence of two properties, `QuestionDetailsByLevel` and `QDetailsByLevel`, of different types. asUwish, you should either pick one or the other, or give one or both of them better names.

Comment: If this is running on a Mac under garbage collection, then point 1 is moot.  However, I never assume garbage collection, because knowing how to manually manage memory is an *extremely* valuable skill.

Comment: Indeed. It's worth knowing how to manually manage memory because you *must* be able to do that if you ever write code for a framework, library, plug-in (of any kind, including color pickers and image units), or iPhone application.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is occurring, if I'm not mistaken, due to the fact that you are modifying the object while you are iterating over its contents. When you remove objects from the list, your termination condition becomes invalid. Try implementing this as a while loop, and be careful to update your termination condition whenever you remove elements from the list. You can also use the debugger to find out where you were out of bounds.